# Strange behaviour with unity and using C# is with GetComponent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Attempting to use unity (c#), writing out a simple GetComponent query using is and type testing:

```
if (this.GetComponent<Animation>() is Animation result)
     Debug.Log("this should not happen: " + result);
```

The object has no Animation component, and I expect the if statement not to execute. But when run, the result is printed out: "this should not happen: null". I was under the impression that if the result is null, the type test should fail and the if statement should not be executed.

If slightly adjusted as follows:

```
if ((this.GetComponent<Animation>() is Animation result) && (result != null))
     Debug.Log("this should not happen: " + result);
```

There is no output, as expected. Trying further:

```
Animation anim = null;
if (anim is Animation)
      Debug.Log("Doesn't display");
```

works as expected, as in nothing happens (if statement not executed). Unity's GetComponent either returns the component, or null. So is it the C# is statement broken here? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity has a [Custom == operator](https://blog.unity.com/engine-platform/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it) so sometimes this causes confusion when working with basic `c#` operators like `?.` and `??` that work on a `object` basis - and maybe this includes pattern matchings using `is`.

They sometimes return a component that is not really `null` but just returns `true` for `== null` checks. Reason behind it are some custom exceptions -  instead of `NullReferenceException` you instead sometimes get `MissingComponentException` - and the fact that those instances are not managed on a `c#` level. The `c#` is just an API level on top of the underlying `c++` Engine core where the instances are actually stored and maintained. So while the GC might not have cleaned up a `c#` component its underlying `c++` instance might already have died.

Why don't you use [`TryGetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.TryGetComponent.html)

```
if(!TryGetComponent<Animation>(out var animation))
{
    Debug.LogError($"This component needs an {nameof(Animation)} component!", this);
    return;
}

// use animation
```

---

In a quick test you can indeed see that `GetComponent<T>`/ `GetComponent(Type)` behave quite different to `TryGetComponent<T>(out T)` / `TryGetComponent(Type, out Component)`.

```
var x = GetComponent<Animation>();
var y = GetComponent(typeof(Animation));
TryGetComponent<Animation>(out var z);
TryGetComponent(typeof(Animation), out var w);
```

for all four `== null` will be `true`.

However, when trying to use the results, you will notice that for the two `GetComponent<T>` and `GetComponent(Type)` you will indeed get `MissingComponnetException` while for `TryGetComponent<T>(out T)` and `TryGetComponent(Type, out Component)` you will get an actual hard `null` and according `NullReferenceException`.

[image]

=> `x` and `y` indeed **are instances** of `Animation`!

Why this is, in particular why they didn't do it consistently the same for `TryGetComponent` - we can not tell. Probably due to [`GetComponent<T>`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/1b4b79be1f4bedfe18965946323fd565702597ac/Runtime/Export/Scripting/Component.bindings.cs#L42) using a directly injected `GetComponentFastPath` and `TryGetComponent<T>` going through [`GameObject.TryGetComponent<T>`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/1b4b79be1f4bedfe18965946323fd565702597ac/Runtime/Export/Scripting/GameObject.bindings.cs#L179) which uses `TryGetComponentFastPath` which might simply be implemented differently. Most probably it is performance reasons.

Comment: The TryGetComponent works as expected. But is it possible for it to also return a component that is not really null? Why would the GetComponent return a "not null component" and the TryGetComponent would return a simple null?

Comment: @Sicyon I tested and indeed that's the case - see bottom of the answer. Indeed quite inconsistent - but might be performance related